# Parsing a math formula

Tags: c

Why these two codes return different values?

```
// #1
// a = 11, b = 24, output = 17.5
printf("Avg: %.1f\n", (float)(a + b) / 2);

// #2
// a = 11, b = 24, output = 17.0
printf("Avg: %.1f\n", (float)((a + b) / 2));
```

I know the problem is in executing, that some thing will be executed first, but that's all I know.

Comment: What is types of `a` and `b`?

Comment: @MikeCAT `short int`.

Comment: `printf("Avg: %.1f\n", ((float)a + b) / 2);}`